# Android App Crashing (Android.developer Tutorials)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following the android.developer tutorials on how to create android apps and have run into an error which I have no idea how to fix. I encountered the error during the lesson about adding action buttons to the menu bar`(http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html)` when you add the menuinflater code.

When I try to run the app it crashes with a message of "Unfortunately, My First App has stopped" and I get the following in the logcat output window in Eclipse:

```
07-01 05:23:20.755: I/Choreographer(1181): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-01 05:23:20.775: W/ResourceType(1181): getEntry failing because entryIndex 2 is beyond type entryCount 2
07-01 05:23:20.775: W/ResourceType(1181): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0c0002 (t=11 e=2) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
07-01 05:23:20.785: D/AndroidRuntime(1181): Shutting down VM
07-01 05:23:20.785: W/dalvikvm(1181): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a39ba8)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 1181
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c0002
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:115)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:35)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:224)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:147)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:199)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:285)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:436)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 05:23:20.795: E/AndroidRuntime(1181):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

main_activity_actions.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" /> 

</menu>
```

Does anybody know how to fix this ?

P.S if anybody knows of a better way to learn Android development over using the android.developer tutorials please do share, the amount of bugs I have encountered trying these tutorials is actually quite ridiculous.

Comment: Post the code also and point out line no 35

Comment: can You post some code of Your project?

Comment: Posted the extra code

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add the ic_action_search drawable or the string resources. The crash indicates that you have missing resources in your project related to the menu xml, or you put them in the wrong resource folder.

Comment: Turns out I was missing the icons for the action_search but I added them and it is still crashing

Comment: Where is crashing ? Please post the new crash too